# How to bypass a value that does not exist in an asynchronous data fetch loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a script that will invoke a function on a blockchain that returns a value. I have to collect these values from 0 to 5999. Unfortunately, several dozen values do not exist, and the loop encountering them stops the operation. How to prevent it?

```
let uriArray = [];
   for (let tokenId = 0; tokenId < 5999; tokenId++) {
    let result = await Gateway.tokenURI(tokenId);
     console.log(result);
     uriArray.push(result);

     if (result = '') {
       continue;
     }
  }
```

Comment: "*several dozen values do not exist, and the loop encountering them stops the operation.*" - what exactly is happening in those cases? What does "*do not exist*" mean, is that the `if (result = '')` thing?

Comment: Btw you've got a typo there: comparison needs  `result == ''` not `result = ''`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `try-catch`, it is stopping I think every time there is a request error.

```
let uriArray = [];

for (let tokenId = 0; tokenId < 5999; tokenId++) {
  try{
      let result = await Gateway.tokenURI(tokenId);
      console.log(result);
      uriArray.push(result);
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }

}
```